# Prolog returns a list instead of several possible strings

Tags: string, list, prolog, logic

```
answer("Yes").
answer("No").
answer("Variable = value").
receive(A) :- answer(A).


2 ?- answer(A).

A = [89, 101, 115]

Yes
```

I want `A = "Yes"` etc. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the list representation of the strings Yes, No and Variable = value.

If you want to instantiate A with the terms Yes, No and Variable = value you should enclose them between single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
answer('Yes').
answer('No').
answer('Variable = value').
```

and if you want to return the terms with the double quotes included, you should include them but also enclose each term with single quotes:

```
answer('"Yes"').
answer('"No"').
answer('"Variable = value"').
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing nothing wrong. `[89, 101, 115]` is the same as `"Yes"`:

```
2 ?- [89, 101, 115] = "Yes".
true.
```

Edit: You can use [this module](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/double_quotes.pl) to do what you want.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I want Prolog to list all the values that I gave the predicate, as they're written as strings... that is, `A = "Yes`, `A = "No"`, `A="Variable = value"`.

Comment: If you want lists of character codes to be printed as strings, see the `set_prolog_flag/2` documentation for your specific Prolog system.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong here, you just see the internal representation of strings.
If you want a more readable output try one of these:

(some of them might only work in SWI-Prolog, but you have tagged it as SWI, so I think that's no problem)

use `name/2` to convert from Number-Lists to atom:

```
?- name(X, "hallo").
X=hallo

?- answer(X), name(Y, X).
X = [89, 101, 115],
Y = 'Yes' ;
```

use `format/2` for output.

```
format('~s',["hallo"]).
hallo
true.

?- answer(X), format('answer is "~s"',[X]).
answer is "Yes"
X = [89, 101, 115] ;
answer is "No"
X = [78, 111].
```

or, if you didn't want to use real strings (codepoint lists) use single quotes:

```
answer('yes').
answer('no').
answer('Variable = value').

?-answer(X).
yes;
…
```